# Ubuntu 12.04 runs too slow

Tags: 12.04, performance

I am a new Ubuntu user. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. My PC has been running much too slowly for the last two days. I tried to find a solution, but I am unable to find it. I tried Unity 2D, but it also runs too slowly.

Specifications:
⠀Processor: Intel Pentium CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz x 2
⠀RAM: 2GB
⠀Available Disk Space: 103GB
⠀Swap: 2GB

Comment: Please provide your system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your condition with my LiveUSB and I have a solution for you.

For example, let us say we installed MySQL on the PC recently and now Ubuntu is too slow. So this is how we'll hunt for the culprit:

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Your screen will be filled with a black terminal.
2. Type sudo -s and then top. Wait for about 5 seconds as Ubuntu refreshes the list.

You will see a list describing the processes running on your screen. Each process has a PID with it. You will also see two columns that show the Virtual Memory consumption (VIRT) and the RAM consumption. In our case, MySQL is what is slowing down the system so it should appear ideally on top of the list, with a high VIRT value.

To kill the process, note it's PID and type kill (pid of the process). And then type the name of the process to restart it. Eg. kill 4525 as 4525 is the PID for our rogue MySQL. And then type mysql.

Repeat this every time your PC slows down and see if a particular process is the culprit each and every time. If it is, open up Terminal and type sudo apt-get purge  and then sudo apt-get install . But before you use this purge command, please tell me which process is eating your PC's Virtual Memory exactly.

Comment: Is there any problem with my system configuration ?

Comment: Google Chrome is using 700-800 MB VIRT..

Comment: WHoa, way too much. Uninstall Chrome, reinstall it and get back to me. And yeah, I reckon you remove all the extensions/add-ons or disable them and then monitor usage. Your PC specs are all-right.